# How to attach a listener to MemoryCache which gets called on expiration of keys?

Tags: c#, memorycache

I am using `MemoryCache` in one of my project to cache some keys and value.

```
private bool CacheEntries<T>(MemoryCache memoryCache, string cacheKey, T value, Configuration config, Action<MemoryCacheEntryOptions> otherOptions = null)
{
    int minutes = randomGenerator.Next(config.LowTime, config.HighTime);

    MemoryCacheEntryOptions options = new MemoryCacheEntryOptions()
    {
        Size = config.Size,
        Priority = config.Priority,
        AbsoluteExpirationRelativeToNow = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(minutes)
    };

    if (otherOptions != null) otherOptions(options);

    CacheKeys.Add(cacheKey);
    memoryCache.Set<T>(cacheKey, value, options);

    return true;
}
```

I have an expiration on my keys as shown above. Also I am storing same key in `CacheKeys` `HashSet` data structure for later use. Is there any way to attach a listener on my `MemoryCache` that whenever it is expiring any items then that listener should get called so that I can remove those keys from `CacheKeys` `HashSet` as well. Basically I want to be consistent with what I have in `CacheKeys` and `MemoryCache`.

Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be using the Platform Extensions object from Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory. You can use the [`MemoryCacheEntryOptions.PostEvictionCallbacks`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.caching.memory.memorycacheentryoptions.postevictioncallbacks?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1#Microsoft_Extensions_Caching_Memory_MemoryCacheEntryOptions_PostEvictionCallbacks) property for the MemoryCacheEntryOptions object when you set the item's value in the cache:

> Gets or sets the callbacks will be fired after the cache entry is evicted from the cache.

Alternatively, if you can change to the System.Runtime.Caching version of `MemoryCache`, you can use the `CacheItemPolicy` when setting the value. From [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.caching.cacheitempolicy):

> A CacheItemPolicy instance contains information that can be associated with a cache entry. For example, **when a cache entry is about to be removed from the cache, a CacheEntryUpdateArguments object is passed to a callback method**. The UpdatedCacheItemPolicy property of the CacheEntryUpdateArguments object can pass a reference to a CacheItemPolicy instance that can include eviction and expiration details about the cache entry.

Another alternative with that version of `MemoryCache` is to call [`CreateCacheEntryChangeMonitor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.caching.memorycache.createcacheentrychangemonitor):

> The CreateCacheEntryChangeMonitor method creates a CacheEntryChangeMonitor instance. This specialized change monitor is used to monitor the cache entries that are specified in the keys collection and to trigger events when the entries change.
>
> A monitored entry is considered to have changed for any of the following reasons:
>
> - The key does not exist at the time of the call to the CreateCacheEntryChangeMonitor method. In that case, the resulting CacheEntryChangeMonitor instance is immediately set to a changed state. This means that when code subsequently binds a change-notification callback, the callback is triggered immediately.
> - The associated cache entry was removed from the cache. This can occur if the entry is explicitly removed, if it expires, or if it is evicted to recover memory